# How do you find the end portal

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’ve had a hard time finding the [End Portal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_portal) in my world and I am wondering what the fastest way to find the [End Portal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_portal) is?

Answer (score 1):

The most common method of finding an [End Portal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_portal) is to use [Eyes of Ender](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Eye_of_Ender) (Combine [Blaze Powder](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Blaze_Powder) with an [Ender Pearl](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Pearl)).